# reset of a ubiquiti networks power ap - no love

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, router, udhcpc

Had to reset our ubnt power ap. It's on fiber, and should pull ip via dhcp. no pppoe weirdness here. even so, it cannot grab an ip. all cables are connected. tried mtu 1500 and 1492. I have ssh access (just a busybox in there) and www admin interface. the dhcp client software is udhcpc, but it's not getting any lease on eth0 (wan). 
what is wrong? fix is worth all my accumulated points :)

Comment: and tried a few other routers as well. they cant get an ip via dhcp either.

Comment: it's worth noting I can view some traffic on the external segment via tcpdump, but the ISP _stubbornly_ assures me ip is obtained with dhcp. However, it's not.